# Exposing a method on a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class CView extends Component {
  someFunc() {
    alert(1);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, there</div>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  getControl() {
    this.cv = <CView />;
    return this.cv;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => this.cv.someFunc()}>Click Me</h2>
        {this.getControl()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Also available on https://codesandbox.io/s/k2174z4jno

When I click on the h2 tag, I get an error saying someFunc is not defined. How can I expose a function of a component so that other components can access it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `this.cv = <CView />;` will not directly return instance of CView component.

```
onClick={() => {
   console.log(this.cv instanceof CView); // false
   this.cv.someFunc();
}}
```

But if you try to use refs you will access it.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.cv = React.createRef();
  }

  onClick() {
    this.cv.current.someFunc();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => this.onClick()}>Click Me</h2>
        <CView ref={this.cv} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It is more "React way" though. https://codesandbox.io/s/vy61q9o8xy